# XSL find certain "leaf" nodes regardless of their depth

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to select all `ns2:resource` nodes which don't have an `ns2:resource` successor. So the `.....` here stands for anything (incl. other/parent `ns2:resource` nodes). How do I go about this?

`<xsl:for-each select="ns2:application/...../ns2:resource">`

The "leaf" in the title is in quotes because ... well, these are not really leaves but they are leaves with respect to the `ns2:resource` nodes i.e. they don't contain other `ns2:resource` nodes in their sub-trees.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns2:application//ns2:resource[not(.//ns2:resource)]">
```

This is untested since there was no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need.